# jQuery Validator, programmatically show errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do something like this:

```
validator.showErrors({ "nameOfField" : "ErrorMessage" });
```

And that works fine, however if I try and do something like this:

```
var propertyName = "nameOfField";
var errorMessage = "ErrorMessage";
validator.showErrors({ propertyName : errorMessage });
```

It throws an 'element is undefined' error.

Comment: var errorMessage = "ErrorMessage" does have a ; at the end in the working code. Typo in this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

```
var propertyName = "nameOfField";
var errorMessage = "ErrorMessage";

var obj = new Object();
obj[propertyName] = errorMessage;

validator.showErrors(obj);
```

---

Is worth to notice that the following three syntaxes are equivalent:

```
var a = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2};

var b = new Object();
b['a'] = 0;
b['b'] = 1;
b['c'] = 2;

var c = new Object();
c.a = 0;
c.b = 1;
c.c = 2;
```

Comment: my only suggested improvement is to just use `{}` instead of `new Object()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an 'element is undefined' error there by the way, is because:

```
var propertyName = "test";
var a = {propertyName: "test"};
```

is equivalent to..

```
var a = {"propertyName": "test"};
```

i.e., you're not assigning the value of propertyName as the key, you're assigning propertyName as a string to it.

Answer (score 0):

That should work fine.  maybe the lack of a ; after the error message is throwing something off.  What browser are your using?

This alert works fine on IE7

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var name = "name";
            var value = "value";
            var obj = eval("({ '"+name+"' : '"+value+"' })");
            alert(obj[name]);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lack of ; is a typo in the question ( doesn't exist in real code). Am using FF

Comment: This example is wrong. If you had set `var name = "blork"` (name is intended to be arbitrary), the example would fail.

Comment: @Justice thanks. I updated it to an example that works. but the other answers are better.